# Capture two arguments with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test MyClass, and I mean by that to test the public function myFunction. This function calls to someMethod from MyService.
I want to check that it passes valid arguments str1 and str2 that were create
in this class.
I was thinking about capture those, but I'm not sure if it is possible to capture 2 arguments, or how to do it.
I don't want to change the visibility if possible

```
class MyService
{
public void someMethod(String str1, String str2);
}

class MyClass
{
private MyService myService;
private String createStrOne(){...};
private String createStrTwo(){...};
....
public void myFunction()
{
  myService = new MyService();
  myService.someMethod(createStrOne(),createStrTwo());
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to check that your method createStringOne() and createStringTwo () return valid arguments, you should make them package protected and test them with unit test. Then you can mock them, if needed, to test myFunction().

Comment: I don't want to change the visibility if possible.
I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 9):

You would simply need two argument captors

```
@Mock
private Service service;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<String> strOneCaptor;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<String> strTwoCaptor;
```

in the test:

```
Mockito.verify(service).someMethod(strOneCaptor.capture(), strTwoCaptor.capture());

assertEquals(strOneCaptor.getValue(), expectedStrOne);
assertEquals(strTwoCaptor.getValue(), expectedStrTwo);
```